# Is ShockWave Therapy Useful For ED or not?

Tags: medications, sex, medical-device, erectile-dysfunction

I read the following in an article from a Facebook page for a clinic in the Lebanon region, and I am trying to know if this choice is good or not?:

> Extracorporeal ShockWave Therapy, or ESWT, is a relatively new treatment for erectile dysfunction that is non-drug, non-surgical and without adverse side effects. It is the same therapy as used in orthopedics, urology and cardiology and which at higher energies is used to break up kidney stones, known as Lithotripsy. The indication for erectile dysfunction has been approved for use in Europe, most countries in the Middle East and South America as well as in Canada.

Is That Correct?

Is ShockWave Useful for ED or not?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE.  Can you please provide details of where you read this?

Comment: @ChrisRogers Given articles like [this](http://www.urologytimes.com/mens-health/shock-waves-may-change-future-ed-therapy), I think he gets a pass on proving prior research.

Comment: @CareyGregory - That article was not mentioned in the question until you put it in there.

Comment: @ChrisRogers  & CareyGregory actually, the article from a Facebook page for a clinic in Lebanon region, and I am trying to know if this choice is good or not?

Comment: @MikeDarwish - Thanks for clarifying things.  I have edited your question to reflect the details you provided.  Can you please [edit your question] to provide a link to the article?

Comment: @ChrisRogers. I don't prefer to but the link directly to this page. maybe you can edit my question and put a link to any article about shockwave topic

Comment: @ChrisRogers I don't understand why you think the article is irrelevant.

Comment: Actually, The main important thing. is this option good for me or not?

Comment: @CareyGregory - What I meant was it was irrelevant to the question as it has not been stipulated as being an article read by the OP.  Articles initially read may have been non-scientific

Comment: actually, i am searching about the answer for this question Is ShockWave Therapy Useful For ED or not?

Comment: Given that it's considered big news in the urology world I wouldn't be surprised if he read about it any number of places and don't see why it's particularly relevant where he saw it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The results of our studies, which also included a double-blind randomized control trial, confirm that LI-ESWT generates a significant clinical improvement of erectile function and a significant improvement in penile hemodynamics without any adverse effects

**Source:**
Gruenwald, I., Appel, B., Kitrey, N. D., & Vardi, Y. (2013). Shockwave treatment of erectile dysfunction. *Therapeutic Advances in Urology*, 5(2), 95–99. doi: [10.1177/1756287212470696](https://doi.org/10.1177/1756287212470696)

Also available from NCBI [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3607492/).

P.S. personal advice: don't trust Facebook articles unless they are linked to reliable sources (e.g. .org, .gov, etc)

Comment: that is why I added a question here, Also why there are no new researches in 2016-2017-2018? i read your source all of resourcess from 2012-2010 ...

Comment: @MikeDarwish - How about https://doi.org/10.1016/j.eururo.2016.05.050 and https://doi.org/10.1016/j.juro.2018.02.070

Comment: @MikeDarwish - [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com) is very useful for searching for recent articles

Comment: Check here for more recent studies (through 2020), including a metastudy conducted in 2019:  https://edtreatment.info/shockwave-therapy-li-eswt-for-erectile-dysfunction/

Answer (score 2):

The research on this topic is a little mixed, but a new study[1] published in January 2019 reviewed almost 40 previous studies, and concluded the shockwave therapy significantly improves erectile function in patients with vasculogenic ED.

One problem remains, however.  The is an external treatment, which in most countries means it does not need government approval; therefore, the government mandated trials have not been done.

Those trials determine the safety and effectiveness of a treatment, but they also establish treatment protocols.  Without those studies, each doctor or clinic may determining their own protocols, and they may not be as effective as treatments administered in peer-reviewed studies.

My current recommendation would be, check it out, but use caution.

[1] Sokolakis, Ioannis; Hatzichristodoulou, Georgios. “Clinical studies on low intensity extracorporeal shockwave therapy for erectile dysfunction: a systematic review and meta-analysis of randomised controlled trials.” International Journal of Impotence Research. Jan 2019.
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41443-019-0117-z

Comment: One of the drawbacks of shockwave therapy has been the high cost...  several thousand dollars for a series of treatments.  This made it impractical for most people to try.  There is a new option - a home device for administering shockwave therapy - which sells for under $1000.  Here's a review:  https://edtreatment.info/phoenix-at-home-shockwave-therapy-for-ed-review/